# naming convention for function and structure names and according to ANSI C standard

Tags: c, ansi-c, c-standard-library

I need to know naming convention for function and structure names and  according to ANSI C standard.

I read that first letter should start with lower case.
Can I use camel case for naming or should I use underscore between two separate.
ex : print_char or printChar
I need to know what does standard states?

Comment: This is completely opinion based, there is no such thing as naming convention, there are many styles that you may adopt, all of them based on different ways of thinking, some of them give more structure to the code, the only important thing is really (**Readabiliy** + **Consistency**).

Comment: The standard defines what names are legal, it doesn't define name convertion like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSI C standard provides little in the way of conventions only rules.
Function, type and variable identifiers may use any alphanumeric symbol A-Za-z0-9 and underscore _. Names may not begin with a number. This is not a convention but the definition for what a legal name may be.

The only convention I am aware of is the recommendation that names beginning with _ and ending with _t should be avoided. As the standard reserves these for use in the future.